# XCTest: how can we inject a class at runtime

Tags: swift, dependency-injection, xcode-ui-testing

For obvious reasons, I don't want to pollute my production code with test code. I am trying to use XCode's ui testing framework. At run time, I want to substitute one of the classes with another that exists only in my testing target.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at [SBTUITestTunnel](https://github.com/Subito-it/SBTUITestTunnel) it might come in handy.

Comment: According to their documentation, SBTUITestTunnel has to components "one to be instantiate in the application and the other in the testing code". I'd really like to avoid having any test related code in production.

Answer (score 0):

You need what is called a test mock.

You create a mock class in your test file that extends the class you wish to mock.

```
class MockHttp extends HttpService {
  var getWasCalledCount = 0

  override func get(request: URLRequest) { 
   getWasCalledCount = getWasCalledCount + 1
  }
}
```

Then in your test you modify your original class property with the mock(I like to to it in the setUp method)

```
override func setUp() {
  var mockHttp = MockHttp()
  classIWantToInjectWithMock = ClassIWantToInjectWithMock(http: mockHttp)
}
```

I hope this helps! Have a nice day!